# onclick event getting executed inspite when onclient click event returns false

Tags: javascript, onclick, onclientclick

I have a validation function written in external JavaScript file.

I call this function using `onclient` property. It was running successfully until I added a stored procedure to insert data in database which gets called on the same button click.

Now my JavaScript function is not getting called and inconsistent data gets stored in database.

Code snippet:

```
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" BackColor="#3333FF" ForeColor="White" 
     Text="Submit" Width="127px" OnClientClick="User_validation();"
     onclick="Button1_Click" />
&nbsp;</td>
```

Comment: That's a wonderful code snippet you have there.

Comment: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" BackColor="#3333FF" ForeColor="White" 
                    Text="Submit" Width="127px" OnClientClick = "User_validation();"  onclick="Button1_Click" />
                    &nbsp;</td>

Comment: Can you not edit your question?